# Edge extension: Validation failed for extension manifest

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

After the review of my Edge extension I got the approval to submit it into the store. However the submission failed with this error.

> File specified by 'background.page' does not exist:
> Extension\PopupApplication\app\index.html?background=1
>
> Validation failed for extension manifest: Extension\manifest.json

The relevant part in the `manifest.json` looks like:

```
"background": {
    "page": "PopupApplication/app/index.html?background=1",
    "persistent": true
}
```

It seems like the validation does not allow query parameters in the `background.page` property. But my logic requires the parameter. Is there any workaround for this or do I have to change my app logic?

The Edge extension works fine locally. Also it works for Chrome and Firefox. I have used the [Microsoft edge Extension Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/porting-chrome-extensions) to port the Chrome extension.

Edit: The simplified folder structure looks like the following

```
+ Assets
+ Extension
|----+ PopupApplication
     |----+ app
     |--------+ index.html
|----+ manifest.json
```

Comment: please check the page path, from the error message, it seems that it can't find the page.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I am sorry, I had a typo. I did an edit for clarification. My guess is that the validator interprets `index.html?background=1` as a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to change our code to successful submit the edge extension. The submission does not allow query parameters in the `background.page` property. This was confirmed by the Microsoft support.